# Filter on Group Expression using lookup to second dataset. SSRS 2012

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2012

I have two datasets (one is a stored procedure written by a vendor that cannot change). Stored procedure is the main dataset.  I am using a second data set to bring back filtered results.  The second dataset contains already filtered records.

Trying to use the Tablix filter:

> =Lookup (Fields!UserGUID.Value,Fields!UserGUID.Value,Fields!MembershipPolicyGUID.Value, "Dataset2")

I have a group that needs to display only the records in Dataset2.

Dataset2 is written using a `where` statement only displaying

> MembershipPolicyGUID not in'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' and '29976BA0-E2D7-494E-A1CE-20E609C76929' (these numbers are stored as text)

I need help in how to filter the records.

I have tried the `<>` in the Tablix filter using the above expression, but it does not work or rather it does not return any records from Dataset2 except those from Dataset1.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The filter should be:
expression =Lookup (Fields!UserGUID.Value,Fields!UserGUID.Value,Fields!MembershipPolicyGUID.Value, "Dataset2")
then operator >
then value 0